# Exact scroll position of ListView

Tags: listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I want to save the position of a `ListView` and then load it so that `ListView` will show up on the exact position that was before. `ListView.ScrollIntoView()` is not precise enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`VerticalOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.verticaloffset.aspx) property to get the offset, then [`ScrollToVerticalOffset`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.scrolltoverticaloffset.aspx) to reset it. Since these are on the `ScrollViewer`, you need to extract it from the visual tree. Note that this code assumes you haven't re-template the `ListView`. This sample assumes the object is named `myListView`:

```
ScrollViewer scrollViewer;
double offset;

public MainPage()
{
  this.InitializeComponent();

  // Have to wait until the templates have been created
  SizeChanged += MainPage_SizeChanged;
}

void MainPage_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
  // Assumes default template
  scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(
    VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(myListView, 0), 0) as ScrollViewer;

  // Not needed any more
  SizeChanged -= MainPage_SizeChanged;
}

private void GetOffsetClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  offset = scrollViewer.VerticalOffset;
}

private void SetOffsetClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  scrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(offset);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It's works very well. Problem occurred when I have `Pivot` with `ListViews` in two `ListViewItems`. I got exception that _"The parameter is incorrect"_ when I try to get ScrollViewer from visual tree.